# Limits on linear acceleration at constant torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, torque

Suppose I have wheels driven by a motor. The wheels make contact with a horizontal surface, so that the wheels accelerate in translational and rotational motion.  If I want to know the linear acceleration of the wheels I use: $a=\alpha r$.

The torque on the wheel is given by:

$\tau=I \alpha \rightarrow \alpha=\frac{\tau}{I}$

The moment of inertia for a solid wheel rotating on its axis is given by $I=\frac{1}{2}mr^2$.

We get: $\alpha=\frac{\tau}{\frac{1}{2}mr^2}$ and so $a=\frac{2r\tau}{mr^2}=\frac{2\tau}{mr}$.

From this I conclude that the linear acceleration gets bigger when I take a smaller radius. But what are the limits of the linear acceleration at a **constant torque** when the radius gets smaller?

Lets say the torque of the motor is 1Nm, the mass is 0.1kg and the radius is 0.01m. In this case the linear acceleration is: $a=\frac{2}{0.001}=2000 m/s^2$. This seems to be way too high. Is the limit the maximum angular velocity of the motor?

Comment: You say you have a wheel driven by a motor.  But then you talk about linear acceleration.  Is this wheel on the ground as well?  Is the ground providing a torque also?

Answer (score 1):

Naturally infinite in newtonian mechanics? If you have constant force and if mass goes to zero acceleration clearly goes to infinite(of course, in the realm of classical newtonian mech.)

Comment: and as a result, if we don't consider relativistic things, it's not weird to have such a big number. To maintain constant torque while radius goes smaller and smaller, the force is going infinitely large too.